# Mysql: deleting rows vs. using a "removed" column

Tags: mysql

I was previously under the impression that deleting rows in an autoincremented table can harm SELECT performance, and so I've been using a tinyint column called "removed" to mark whether an item is removed or not.

My SELECT queries are something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE removed = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25
```

But I'm wondering whether it does, in fact, make sense to just delete those rows instead. Less than 1% of rows are marked as "removed" so it seems dumb for mysql to have to check whether removed = 0 for each row.

So can deleting rows harm performance in any way?

Comment: my suggestion is to keep the records and puts flags just like what you did, putting a column for "deleted". "Delete" could in a way affect the indices of your table such that when you delete a row you must update the rest of the indices to reflect that rest of the indices depend on the value of the deleted row's index

Answer (score 3):

That depends a lot on your use case - and on your users. Marking the row as deleted can help you in various situations:

- if a user decides "oh, I *did* need that item after all", you don't need to go through the backups to restore it - just flip the "deleted" bit again (note potential privacy implications)
- with foreign keys, you can't just go around deleting rows, you'd break the relationships in the database; same goes for security/audit logs
- you aren't changing the number of rows (which may decrease index efficiency if the removed rows add up)

Moreover, when properly indexed, in my measurements, **the impact was always insignificant** (note that I wrote "measurements" - go and profile likewise, don't just blindly trust some people on the Internet). So, my advice would be "use the `removed` column, it has significant benefits and no significant negative impact".

Comment: I currently don't include the "removed" column in my index. Say I have an index on submitter,id (which allows me to grab all items from a particular submitter and sort by their id). If I add "removed" as the 3rd column in that index so it is submitter,id,removed won't that basically double the size of the index? A two column index makes logical sense to me in terms of how mysql structures the data, but I'm not sure how a three column index could be structured efficiently.

Comment: @makeee: The size of an index doesn't depend *directly* on number of columns, but on their sizes and data types. Adding a `TINYINT` to the indexed columns will not increase the index size significantly (no, it will definitely not double the size). As for the efficiency, my __guess__ would be `submitter,id,removed` or `submitter,removed,id`, but you need to measure for yourself how it works in your specific queries with your specific data.

Comment: Could you explain why index efficiency would be decreased due to deleted rows? Can that be fixed by an optimize table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think *deleting rows harm on select query*. Normally peoples takes an extra column named deleted [removed in your case] to provide a **restore** like functionality. So if you are not providing restore functionality then you can delete the row it will not affect the select query as far as I know. *But while deleting keep relationships in mind they should also get deleted or will result in error or provide wrong results.*

Answer (score 0):

You just fill the table with more and more records which you don't need. If you don't plan to use them in the future, I don't think you need to store them at all. If you want to keep them anyway, but don't plan to use them often, you can just create a temp table to hold your "removed" records.